# alias to replace a text in file

Tags: grep, alias, sed, awk, vi

here is a  practical situation.I facing some of my files where there is a common string in these files.I usually will open vi and do some thing like

```
:%s/text/replacement/g
```

and I have to do it in many files many many times.
Is there some easy way to do it or some sort of alias that I can create for the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use find for finding the target files and then pipe it to sed:

> find | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'

Only replace in .txt files:

> find . -name "*.txt" -print | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'

(from [this blog post](http://rushi.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/find-replace-across-multiple-files-in-linux/))

Answer (score 4):

Ah yes, time for a perl oneliner.  How about this?

```
perl -pi -e 's/old text/new text/' file
```

or maybe you want to change all the *.txt files in the current directory?  In that case, how about combining it with [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel perl -i.bak -pe 's/foo/bar/' ::: *.txt
```

With parallel, the `:::` means *use eveything after this as input files*.

or, to change **all** the txt files in the current directory and **below**:

```
find . -name \*txt -print0 | parallel -q -0 perl -i.bak -pe 's/old text/new text/'
```

Note the `-i.bak` saves a backup copy of every file that you change, in case you make a mistake.  You can leave that out if you are feeling dangerous.

Anyway obviously the `sed` answer is the standard one, but there are some fun alternative ways to do it too.  Also if you have a lot of files gnu parallel will be significantly faster as it runs multiple copies in parallel (as one would hope, given the name).

Comment: this is really some new thing for me.I will test it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out sed, something like this:

```
sed -i 's/text/replacement/g' file
```